Is there a built-in way to enable encryption for SmartStore within the Salesforce Mobile SDK or additional configuration is required?
Our team recently developed a custom mobile app using Salesforce Mobile SDK (version 12.0.1) and utilized the SmartStore feature for local data storage. After conducting a penetration test on the app, we discovered that the SmartStore database files are not encrypted.
We would like to understand if there is a built-in way to enable encryption for SmartStore within the Salesforce Mobile SDK or if additional configuration is required on our end.
Questions:
Does the SF Mobile SDK ensure that all data within SmartStore soups is encrypted automatically, or are there certain data types or fields that require manual encryption? How can we verify that the encryption is successfully applied to SmartStore soups, both globally and at the field level?
Are there any known limitations or bugs in the current version of the Salesforce Mobile SDK (12.0.1) we are using related to data encryption in SmartStore?
Is there any additional configuration needed in the React Native app to fully encrypt data for each SmartStore soup? Below is the screenshot of the code on how to register the soup.
